# Best way to load data into Azure synapse analytics

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am new to this Azure environment. We are planning to load some DB data into Azure synapse analytics. What are the best ways to connect and load from SSMS (we have database backup file) to Azure synapse analytics .Gone through several documentations and really confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Reshma, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure synapse analytics(ADW) doesn't support import data from the flat file directly. Even with SSMS:
[image]

The best may be using [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction), the datasset connectors support Azure SQL database, SQL server and Azure synapse analytics.

You could reference these Azure tutorials bellow:

1. [Load data into Azure Synapse Analytics by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-sql-data-warehouse)
2. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)
3. [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly SQL
   Data Warehouse) by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)
4. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

For example, if the Source DB data is located in on-premise SQL Server, you could set the SQL Server as source dataset and Azure synapse analytics as the sink dataset. You also need install the [self-host integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to connect to the on-premise source from Data Factory.